# Correct conversion from rotation matrix to (pitch, roll, yaw) for Mayavi/Vtk

Tags: python, rotation, vtk, mayavi, rotational-matrices

### My problem

I want to rotate a `mayavi.mlab.imshow` object with a 3x3 rotation matrix. The only method I could find for rotating this object is through setting the object's `actor.orientation` to `[pitch, roll, yaw]` (this order is inherited from vtk). My only problem is that I cannot find a way to convert a rotation matrix to the parameters requested by mayavi.

How do I rotate an object in mayavi with a rotation matrix or what transformation should I use to obtain the correct (pitch, roll and yaw) used by Mayavi/Vtk?

### A near solution

I have found some code [over here](https://github.com/awesomebytes/delta_robot/blob/master/src/transformations.py) to transform a rotation matrix to different types of Euler angles (according to the order of rotation). Correct me at this point if I am wrong in assuming Euler angles is equivalent to pitch, roll, yaw. I have tried all the different conversions, but failed to find a correct one.

### Trying every combination

I tested all the different transformations by rotating x, y and z vectors with my rotation matrix and testing the paramaters on the `mayavi.mlab.imshow` object. I used all the available transforms on both `R` and `transpose(R)` along with using the Euler  the parameters in all 9 available orders, but could not find a correct combination:

```
import pylab as pl
import cameraTools #my own lib
from mayavi import mlab

im = pl.imread('dice.png', format='png')[:,:,0]*255 #1 color channel
rot = pl.r_[30, 80, 230]

R_orig = cameraTools.composeRotation(*(rot*pl.pi/180))
RList = [R_orig, R_orig.T]
for ii, inOrder in enumerate(['sxyz','sxzx','syxz','szxz','rzyx','rxzx','rzxy','rzxz','sxyx','syzx','syxy','szyx','rxyx','rxzy','ryxy','rxyz','sxzy','syzy','szxy','szyz','ryzx','ryzy','ryxz','rzyz']):
    tries = 0
    for outOrder in [[0,1,2], [0,2,1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]]:
        for R in  RList:
            for vector, color in zip([[800, 0, 0], [0, 800, 0], [0, 0, 800]],
                                     [(1., 0., 0.), (0., 1., 0.), (0., 0., 1.)]):
                c = pl.c_[[0, tries*1000, ii*1000]]
                if ii == 0 and tries == 0: vector = pl.r_[vector]*5 #point out the first vector
                lin = R_orig.dot(pl.c_[[0,0,0], vector]) + c
                mlab.plot3d(*lin,
                            color = color,
                            tube_radius=5)

            lin3D    = mlab.imshow(im, colormap="gray")
            rxyz = pl.array(cameraTools.euler_from_matrix(R, inOrder))*180/pi
            i,j,k = outOrder
            lin3D.actor.orientation = [rxyz[i], rxyz[j], rxyz[k]]
            lin3D.actor.position    = c.flatten()
            tries +=1


mlab.draw()
mlab.show()
```

Output from Mayavi, the top left item is the starting point.

[image: Mayavi output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it seems I did not concentrate hard enough. The answer is in row 3, column 5 with `syxz` input order and `'[1,0,2]'` output order. I now use the following function to convert a Rotation matrix to the required Euler angles:

```
def rotationToVtk(R):
    '''
    Concert a rotation matrix into the Mayavi/Vtk rotation paramaters (pitch, roll, yaw)
    '''
    def euler_from_matrix(matrix):
        """Return Euler angles (syxz) from rotation matrix for specified axis sequence.
        :Author:
          `Christoph Gohlke <http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/>`_

        full library with coplete set of euler triplets (combinations of  s/r x-y-z) at
            http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html

        Note that many Euler angle triplets can describe one matrix.
        """
        # epsilon for testing whether a number is close to zero
        _EPS = np.finfo(float).eps * 5.0

        # axis sequences for Euler angles
        _NEXT_AXIS = [1, 2, 0, 1]
        firstaxis, parity, repetition, frame = (1, 1, 0, 0) # ''

        i = firstaxis
        j = _NEXT_AXIS[i+parity]
        k = _NEXT_AXIS[i-parity+1]

        M = np.array(matrix, dtype='float', copy=False)[:3, :3]
        if repetition:
            sy = np.sqrt(M[i, j]*M[i, j] + M[i, k]*M[i, k])
            if sy > _EPS:
                ax = np.arctan2( M[i, j],  M[i, k])
                ay = np.arctan2( sy,       M[i, i])
                az = np.arctan2( M[j, i], -M[k, i])
            else:
                ax = np.arctan2(-M[j, k],  M[j, j])
                ay = np.arctan2( sy,       M[i, i])
                az = 0.0
        else:
            cy = np.sqrt(M[i, i]*M[i, i] + M[j, i]*M[j, i])
            if cy > _EPS:
                ax = np.arctan2( M[k, j],  M[k, k])
                ay = np.arctan2(-M[k, i],  cy)
                az = np.arctan2( M[j, i],  M[i, i])
            else:
                ax = np.arctan2(-M[j, k],  M[j, j])
                ay = np.arctan2(-M[k, i],  cy)
                az = 0.0

        if parity:
            ax, ay, az = -ax, -ay, -az
        if frame:
            ax, az = az, ax
        return ax, ay, az
    r_yxz = pl.array(euler_from_matrix(R))*180/pi
    r_xyz = r_yxz[[1, 0, 2]]
    return r_xyz
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with VTK and I'm curious, did you find the axis order of VTK? From your answer it looks like it's YXZ, is that correct? I'm trying to take Euler Angles (roll, pitch, yaw) and turn it into VTK camera orientation for a VR project but I'm getting stuck similar to you. Any advice?

Comment: @Jacksonkr, sorry I forgot most of this. From the `return r_xyz` line it seems as though the axis order is r_xyz.